# Centrar botón en pantalla con Bootstrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

Quisiera saber cómo puedo hacer para centrar un botón en el contenedor usando Bootstrap, es decir, en el centro de la pantalla tanto vertical como horizontalmente. Lo intenté de varias maneras pero no puedo. Mi código es el siguiente:

```css
html,
body {
  background-image: url("fondo.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
}

.container-fluid {
  background-color: cyan;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.col {
  background-color: pink;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row w-100">
      <div class="col">
        <button class="btn btn-danger center-block"> A regular button </button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:**

```css
html, body {
     background-image: url("fondo.jpeg");
     background-size: cover;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     height: 100%;
    }
    
    
    .container-fluid {
     background-color: cyan;
     border: 2px solid black;
     display: flex;
       justify-content: center; 
    }
    
    
    .col {
     background-color: pink;
     border: 2px solid black;
    
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
     <title>Bootstrap</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" 
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
      
    
     <div class="container-fluid h-100"> 
      <div class="row w-100 align-items-center">
       <div class="col text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-danger regular-button"> A regular button </button>
       </div> 
      </div>
    
    
     </div>
    
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: En realidad lo que quiero es centrar el botón en la pantalla, tanto horizontal como verticalmente

Comment: Si, disculpa, leí por arriba. Ahí edite, mira si es lo que deseas. También puedes agregar `justify-content-center` en la row

Comment: Genial, funcionó. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

```css
html, body {
    background-image: url("fondo.jpeg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
}


.container-fluid {
    background-color: cyan;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;    
}


.col {
    background-color: pink;
    border: 2px solid black;

}
.v-center{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>


    <div class="container-fluid h-100"> 
        <div class="row w-100">
            <div class="col v-center">
                <button class="btn btn-danger d-block mx-auto"> A regular button </button>
            </div>  
        </div>


    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba este código:

```
<div class="col text-center">
   <button class="btn btn-danger"> A regular button </button>
</div>
```

El `text-center` no funciona si tienes la clase `center-block`. Por lo que si le quitas esa clase y le añades la otra te debe de funcionar.

Comment: En realidad lo que quiero es centrar el botón en la pantalla, tanto horizontal como verticalmente